# Resizing bitmap with keep aspect ratio, error

Tags: android, bitmap, resize

I resized the image while keeping the aspect ratio of the image, works successfully on width or square images, however, it creates some distortion in height pictures, creates gaps around it as seen in the picture, how can i fix this?

[image: image aspccet ratio]

The code I use;

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(resize(bitmap, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels));

private Bitmap resize(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
        float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        int finalWidth = maxWidth;
        int finalHeight = maxHeight;
        if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
            finalWidth = (int) ((float)maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
        } else {
            finalHeight = (int) ((float)maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
        }
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
        return image;
    } else {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: The gaps you're talking about are the "spaces" you wrote in photo?

Comment: @Gabriel14 yes the spaces I wrote in the photo are red